# two for command LOOP will not work

Tags: batch-file

index.txt:

```
2 6
8 12
```

text.txt number 1~15 are head number.

```
1
2
3 a
4 b
5 c
6
7
8
9 e
10 f
11 g
12
13
14
15
```

I want to print number 2~6  and 8~12 line
code:

```
    setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
    for /f "tokens=1,2,* delims= " %%a in (index.txt) do (

    set /a start=%%a
    set /a final=%%b

    for /f "skip=%start% tokens=1,* delims=:" %%i in ('findstr /n ".*" text.txt') do (if %%i LEQ %final%  echo %%j)
    )　
    endlocal
```

but this not work

Comment: Please take the [tour], read [Ask]. "not work" is not a precise enough problem statement.  What does it do?  What did you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=:" %%i in ('findstr /n ".*" text.txt') do (if %%i GEQ %%a  if %%i LEQ %%b  echo %%j)
```

No need to use `start` or `final` at all.